# how to query many to many relationship in Linq to EF5

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-5

I am learning EF5 and building a small website which simply displays some songs and singers. As a song can be sung by more than one singer and a singer will have many songs so my EF model as below.

[image]

I want to display all the list of songs with its relevant singers in a table so I wrote a query and this is so far I have.

```
Dim res = context.Songs _
        .SelectMany(Function(song) song.Artists, Function(s, a) New With
                                                                {.SongTitle = s.SongTitle, _
                                                                .ArtistName = a.ArtistName, _
                                                                 .Lyrics = s.Lyrics})
```

But I am having the result like below.

[image]

You will see Lucky is displayed twice in the table. I don't want that to happen. I just want to display it once but have join two singers in the Artist column. I tried to read tutorials and many forum posts but those tutorials don't get this complicated.

So how can i get change the query to return something like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must write my answer with C#, hopefully you are able to translate it into VB.

I would do two changes:

- First, simply use `Select` instead of `SelectMany` in this situation.
- Second, introduce a named ViewModel instead of an anonymous type because it allows you to add a method or custom readonly property that will be helpful later.

The ViewModel would look like this:

```cs
public class SongViewModel
{
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
    public string Lyrics { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> ArtistNames { get; set; }

    public string ArtistNamesString
    {
        get { return string.Join(", ", ArtistNames); }
    }
}
```

Then you can use this query:

```cs
var res = context.Songs.Select(s => new SongViewModel
{
    SongTitle = s.SongTitle,
    Lyrics = s.Lyrics,
    ArtistNames = s.Artists.Select(a => a.ArtistName)
});
```

Now, to list the result, you can use a loop like this (example with console output):

```cs
foreach (var item in res)
{
     Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1} {2}",
         item.SongTitle, item.Lyrics, item.ArtistNamesString);
}
```

This lists each song only once and the artist names are displayed as a comma separated list.